# Coverting a FLOAT column to VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a phone number column defined as - be ready - a FLOAT!

I want to change that to a varchar.

My questions is, can I just change the type on the fly, or do I have to create another column and then copy/convert (that second option would disrupt certain pieces of code that are already using the current column, and it may be a challenge to find them all).

Thanks!

Comment: Have any of these approaches helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add the new column and copy the existing data and then remove the old column.

Comment: Or create a temp column, copy the existing data. Delete the old column. Recreate the old column under the same name but the right type, copy the data in the new old column. Delete temp column

Answer (score 1):

Try using the str() function.

Select Str(float_field, 25, 5)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

Comment: Avada, but that was not my shaila.